# ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable | how to fix

Tags: android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

Hey m getting an error | list view not working

```
public class introduction extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_intro, container, false);
        TextView t =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t.setText(ag);
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,b);
        ListView lv= (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lb);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Error:
 constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; introduction cannot be converted to Context)

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that `introduction` it's a Fragment and ArrayAdapter cosnstructor takes a Context as argument. So you cannot pass a Fragment as Context. Use `getActivity()` instead or pass the Context from Activity to `instruction` Fragment and use it inside the fragment.